# Can not to src my photos in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have a folder with the images on the root of my project but i can not access them even if i use the `<?php echo base_url();images/...` The problem is occured only in one view with that url  `http://localhost/PR/register/index/`

Comment: is the URL intact? if you echo that base_url;/images/.., what does it show? 

Can you put that link in a browser or does it break there aswell?

Comment: yes if i echo the url i can see the correct path, but for some reason it does not load the images.. In the current page i have used codigniter pagination if that helps you, thanks!

Comment: when i paste the path from the echo on the browser i get an 403 error messages...

Comment: what is the server returning for the image request? 404? 403? You can see that information by pressing F12 in chrome for example, for a list of all requests

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting your closing PHP tag.  Rather than do

```
<?php echo base_url();images/...
```

You need to do

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/filename.jpg" />
```

If this still isn't working make sure you inspect the value of your `src` attribute and check that the path is correct.  You may also want to check the permissions on your `images` folder is correct too

Comment: Sorry my fault, i forgot to post the php tag in here, i have already tried your suggestion but unfortunatelly it did not work..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest edit :

You're getting a 403 error, The image is fine. You simply don't have access to that directory. Fix your permissions and it should work fine.